# How to program own real time transport protocol for Silverlight Video/Audio Conferencing over a network?

Tags: silverlight, sockets, video, audio, rtp

Hi 
I have created a Silverlight Application for audio/video conferencing using TCP. But due to slow speed during tranferring stream bytes over the network. While google the situation i find that there is no any support for real time transport protocols, such as RTP in silverlight. So, can anyone guide me or refer some links to perform this task?
Thanks in advance 
Any Suggestion or Help will appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the stream in raw bytes? Have you tried sending a compressed byte stream and decompressing it at the other end? This may speed up the transfer process but would cause the client to work harder to decompress it.

Comment: almost all audio/video formats in use today already use compression internally so the benefit of doing this is negligible, there's a huge downside though.